# Executing an EXE in your $PATH, which starts with a numeric value, in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, constants, exe, numeric

So 7z.exe is in my $PATH environment variable.

```
PS C:\Users\jimmeh> 7z.exe
Bad numeric constant: 7.
At line:1 char:2
+ 7 <<<< z.exe
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (7:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadNumericConstant
```

Besides renaming the EXE, is there a way to do this, or is it a bug in Powershell?

Comment: A workaround is "cmd.exe /c 7z.exe", but that's hardly ideal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It work like

```
& '.\7z.exe'
```

if you want to specify an archive to extract

& '.\7z.exe' e your.zip

Comment: Makes perfect sense for a shell that has a scripting language.

Comment: If you do this lots, you could set an alias in your profile to make it easier: `set-alias zip 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe'`

Comment: The `&` in itself is enough, no need for `.\ `... I have it on PATH: so `& 7z a ...args...`

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer a problem with Powershell 4.0

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855